# how to convert returned ascii arithmetic symbols, so it can be used with operands

Tags: c++

How could I use arithmetic operation symbols if its assigned to variable and need to return for evaluation of simple arithmetic problems --> from the way its constructed in the code below. How? or any other suggestions welcomed thanks in advance

```
int arithmeticType();
int main() {
    int arithmeticSymbol = arithmeticType();
    int x, y;
    int result = 0;
    srand(time(NULL) );

    printf( "Type is: %d\n", arithmeticSymbol );

    //how to get result of (x + y)using arithmeticSymbol?????

    printf( "The result %d %d %d", 4, arithmeticSymbol, 3 );

    return 0;
}

int arithmeticType() {
    int type, token;
    printf("Select the type of arithmetic operation to perform:\n"
        "\t1. Addition.\n\t2. Subtraction.\n\t3. Multiplication.\n\t"
            "4. Mixture of all three. --> ");

    scanf("%d", &type);
    switch ( type ) {
        case 1:
            token = '+'; 
            break;
        case 2:
            token = '-';
            break;
        case 3:
            token = '*';
            break;
        case 4:
            //get random value between 1-3
            token = rand() % 3 + 1;
            if ( token == 1 ) {
                token = '+';
            }
            else if ( token == 2 ) {
                token = '-';
            }
            else {
                token = '*';
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong input");
            break;        
    }
    return token;    
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Another conditional statement, if the operator is `'+'` then do addition, if it's `'-'` then do subtraction, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to apply the operator. You also need to consider your types - if you just use integers, things like 3/2 may not do what you expect...

If it was me I'd probably use an `enum` instead of the ASCII operator code.

```
int getResult(int op1, int op, int op2)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (op== '+') {
        result = op1 + op2;
    }
    else ...

    return result;
}
```

You would call it like: `printf( "The result of %d %c %d is: %d", 4, getOperation, 3, getResult(4, getOperation, 3) );` (note printing the operator as `%d` wont do what you expect and the name `getOperator` is very misleading.

Comment: `int operator`? Really? :P

Comment: Ok, so I've been doing C# for too long ;-)